# Showing that the square of any integer is of the form $3k$ or $3k+1$ for some integer $k$

Tags: integers

> Show that the square of every integer is of the form $3k$ or $3k + 1$, for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. Conclude that $3n^2-1$ is never a perfect square.

Sorry if I do not attach my effort. The truth is I am new to this. I would appreciate any help !!!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a MathJax tutorial

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**  Every integer is of the form $3k$, $3k+1$, or $3k+2$.  What do you get when you square those?